# spring data solr , set timezone UTC

Tags: spring-data-solr

all  the data in solr are in UTC, my spring boot app is running on a EST JVM ( Tomcat).

Is there is a way to configure solrClient/ SolrTemplat to use UTC timezone for Date?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this in you spring boot app file

    `@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));   // It will set UTC timezone
    }`